# ¿Cómo puedo quitar las comillas en un valor numérico al crear un JSON?

Tags: php, json

¿Cómo puedo quitar las comillas del `id` en un JSON generado con PHP?

Mi código:

```php
$students = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $id = $row['student_id'];
    $student_name = $row['student_name'];
    $student_image = $row['student_image'];
    $student_course = $row['student_course'];

    $students[] = array(
        'id'=> $id,
        'student_name'=> $student_name,
        'student_image'=> $student_image,
        'student_course'=> $student_course,
        );
}

$close = mysqli_close($connection) 
or die("An unexpected error has occurred in the disconnection of the database");


$json_string = '{"students":' . json_encode($students) . '}';
print ($json_string)
```

Quiero obtener este resultado:

```
"students": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "student_name": "David John",
    "student_image": "avatar.jpg",
    "student_course": "10",
  },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En tu caso, como respondió @lois6b, es trivial redefinir a mano el array para obligar a `json_encode` a devolver un número.

Para el caso general, sin embargo, cuando no tienes idea de lo que puede contener el array que vas a entregarle a `json_encode`, puedes pasarle un segundo parámetro ([una constante JSON](http://php.net/manual/es/json.constants.php)) que modifica la forma como éste entrega los resultados.

Usando tu ejemplo, en vez de

```
$json_string = '{"students":' . json_encode($students) . '}';
print ($json_string);
```

Quedaría como:

```
$json_string = '{"students":' . json_encode($students,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ) . '}';
print ($json_string);
```

Aunque, en realidad, yo encuentro que sería más elegante hacer

```
$json_string = json_encode(['students' => $students], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );
print ($json_string);
```

Comment: me gusta! yo de [tag:php] y [tag:json] se mas bien poco, así que contesté con lo que sé hehe

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que en `$id` se está almacenando un `string`.

deberias pasar ese `string`a `int`: (ten cuidado por si la conversion no puede hacerse)

```
 $id_int = (int)$id;
```

y luego:

```
'id'=> $id_int,
```

---

O directamente:

```
'id'=> (int)$id,
```

Comment: Simplemente he añadido (int) antes del $id quedaria asi 'id'=> (int)$id

Comment: @KarimXpert por supuesto haha cada uno tiene sus manias al programar y me acostumbro a hacerlo en multiples lineas. Me alegra ser de ayuda, un saludo

Comment: estoy esperando a que pasen los minutos xD

Comment: @KarimXpert hahah me lo imaginaba (nunca recuerdo cuantos minutos son)

Comment: @lois6b te quitaron el honor de ser la respuesta oficial, pero ten mi voto solidario porque tu respuesta es correcta para la pregunta puntual.

Comment: :O no necesito votos solidarios * kiddin * HAHAH na, muchas gracias. Me sorprendería que no marcara la tuya que le da mil vueltas a mi respuesta. Yo esperaba que nadie contestara pero no cayó la breva xDD Congrats

Comment: Sorry quería daros mi voto a los dos pero parece que solo me permite uno xD

Comment: @KarimXpert el voto te lo permite a los dos, el aceptar solo a una respuesta. Considero que la respuesta de amenadiel es mucho mejor y por ello deberia ser la marcada como aceptada.